# Find Distribution of Ratio of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am working on the following:

Let $U$ ~ $U(0,1)$ random variable and X be an independent random variable with $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$.  Determine the distribution of $Y=X/\sqrt{U}.$

Here's my attempt:
$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(\frac{X}{\sqrt{U}} \le y)= P(\frac{X}{y} \le \sqrt{U})=P(\frac{X^2}{y^2} \le U)=1-F_{U}(\frac{X^2}{y^2})=1-\frac{X^2}{y^2}.$

I am not sure how to deal with X random variable since my work so far doesn't incorporate the information that we are given that $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$.

Comment: I would expect $F_Y(y)+F_Y(-y)=1$ by symmetry and $F_Y(-1)=F_Y(0)=F_Y(1)=\frac12$

Comment: How do we know $F_{Y}$ is symmetric?

Comment: $Y$ has a distribution symmetric about $0$ because of the presence of $X$ as an independent multiplicative factor.

Comment: How does this compare to the answer provided below?  I am kind of confused if the two responses are in agreement.

Comment: Pepe Silvia's answer does meet my conditions

Comment: Do you have any insight on how to derive the last two lines of his solution? That's the only part that's kicking me up right now.

Comment: For a more direct solution, first find the PDF of $V=1/\sqrt{U}$ by the general Jacobian method, which yields instantly $$f_V(v)=2v^{-3}\mathbf 1_{v>1}$$ then deduce the PDF $f_Y$ of $Y=X/\sqrt{U}=XV$ as $$f_Y(y)=\tfrac12f_V(|y|)=|y|^{-3}\mathbf 1_{|y|>1}$$ Using PDFs rather than CDFs seems rather simpler in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem in your calculations is assuming $y$ is positive when you divide by it in the inequality. Since you're combining continuous and discrete random variables this doesn't classify as a general method by any means, but see the following. For $y>0$,

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{P}[Y\leq y] 
&=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{\sqrt{U}}\leq y\right] \\
&=\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{\sqrt{U}}\leq y\Bigg|X=-1\right]\times\frac{1}{2}
+\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{X}{\sqrt{U}}\leq y\Bigg|X=1\right]\times\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{1}{y^2}\leq U\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\max\left\{0,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2y^2}\right\}
\end{align}$$ 
as $\mathbb{P}[U>x]=\max\{0,1-x\}$ for $x>0$.

See if you can similarly show that, for $y<0$, $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}[Y\leq y]=\min\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2y^2}\right\}$.

Comment: I am confused on the last two steps of the logic you provided.  How do we get $1/2 + 1/2 \mathbb{P}[\frac{1}{y^2} \le U]$ as = $1/2 + max \{0, \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2y^2} \} \mathbb{P} [U >x] = max \{0,1-x\}$?

Comment: Using the maximum function is just a condensed way to express the piecewise function itself. Since the support of $U$ is $(0, 1)$, we know that $\Pr\{U > 1\} = 0$ and thus you split the case into $y^{-2} > 1$ and $0 < y^{-2} < 1$.

Comment: This looks like a good example where using CDFs instead of PDFs only confuses things. Even knowing the result, recovering it from these expressions requires some care, hence...